# Daily New Users seems to be Incorrect in Fabric Answers

Tags: google-fabric

We have a Android and iOS version of our app. The number of active users on iOS is aproximately 25% of the active user on the Android app.

It happens that the count of Daily New Users of the Android app is always far less then the iOS's. And the this number does not seems to match the increase in Daily Active Users.

The app is br.com.bb.android.

Anyone has an idea of what may be causing this?

Would be great if someone in the Fabric team could take a look into this.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Are you removing these temp directories on iOS during your app's startup? NSTemporaryDirectory() // <app-sandbox>/tmp
NSCachesDirectory // <app-sandbox>/Library/Caches

Comment: No, we are not touching those files. The number that first caught our attention was the Android's.

Comment: Did more digging in on this and I think we've found the issue. If an installation events happens more then 7 days ago, we do not count that as valid. I'm not going to share numbers here, but as a percentage, we see about 60% of your installs falling outside the date range we consider valid which is the likely cause of the discrepancy.

Comment: That's probably it then. We just integrated Crashlytics. It should take some days for the date to stabilize. Are this 7 days just from new installations or updates aswell?

Comment: Anytime and it's only for installations.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my app. The Android numbers seems to be correct, but the iOS numbers not. Although the iOS numbers show much more new users than Android, the correct would be the opposite (the app is tv.ip.mano).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

For apps where they may come pre-installed or not be opened for a length of time, then the installs may not be counted as a daily new user.

A new user will only be counted if the time between downloading the app and opening it (with foreground activity) is less then 7 days.

Comment: Hi Mike - What could cause the numbers to skew in the other direction? For example, app units in iTunes connect are around 1.9k, while daily new users are above 2.5k. Daily new users on Fabric always seem to be 25% above app units in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Hey @r3c0d3 if a user installs the apps in multiple different devices or deletes and re-installs the app, we could be higher than iTunes Connect.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I don't think we'd have around 25% of our users deleting and re-installing the app, or installing on multiple devices. Our iPad app user share is around 1%. Could setting a userIdentifier on our Crashlytics sharedInstance after an in-app registration have any affect on these numbers? Either way, love the crash reporting service, extremely helpful!

Comment: The only other thing I just thought of is if a user opts-out of data sharing with Apple or Developers. Setting the userIdentifier won't affect these numbers.