# Fabric data different from iTunes Connect data

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, google-fabric

Our Daily New User-count from Fabric is consistently bigger than the App Units per day that we get from iTunes Connect.

Fabric defines Daily New Users as

> The number of new app installations across all devices seen on a given
>   day.

And iTunes connect defines App Units as

> The number of first-time app downloads made on the App Store using iOS
>   8 or tvOS 9, or later. App updates, downloads from the same Apple ID
>   onto other devices, and redownloads to the same device are not
>   counted. Family Sharing downloads are included for free apps, but not
>   for paid apps.

What can cause this discrepancy? I can see many reasons for how Fabric could report a lower number (such as users downloading the app but never opening it, or [waiting too long to open it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43640758/1373572)), but not the other way around. Our average send-usage-to-developers opt-in rate is 23%, but that does not affect the App Units number if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Have you found the reason behind that?

Comment: In my case showing download units in itunesconnect 150 while in fabric show 20 new users only.

Answer (score 1):

Is your app available on both iPhone and iPad? If so, then the fact that, as you point out, *Apple doesn't count downloads from the same Apple ID onto other devices* might be causing this discrepancy? You can install iPhone apps on your iPad even if it's not officially supported, so the rule might still be affecting your app. Also, if your app is a paid app, then the Family sharing rules would also affect the numbers. I've actually wondered how iTunes counts new users, so thanks for that info!

I'm not sure why the numbers are consistently bigger for you on Fabric, because for my app they alternate a bit.

Comment: I never thought about that scenario. Let me check the device ratio from iTunes Connect and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you might have got the answer. If not follow the link below http://help.apple.com/itc/appanalytics/#/itc7bea1545f

Comment: Meaning of your answer is shown more new user in fabric compare to download units in itunesconnect. Right?

Comment: In my case showing download units in itunesconnect 150 while in fabric show 20 new users only.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are users who don't opt-in app analytics data.

> Apple only shows data from users who have agreed to share their
>   diagnostics and usage information with app developers.